# Laravel 4 routing parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie when it comes to  Laravel and so far really enjoying it. I'm using L4 and would like some help with the routing which I'm still trying to get my head around.

I would like the uri `domain.com/{username}`
I can get `domain.com/{user_id}` and Laravel looks up the user but I cannot seem to use the username as a parameter.

EDIT:

I am using a model for user routing

```
Route::model('user', 'User');
```

And then trying to route

```
Route::get('/{user}', 'sampleController@viewUser');
```

Also note that it's after all other routes

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi there and welcome to Laravel!

You can use this route registration.

```
Route::get('{username}', function($username){
    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->fist();
    if (! is_null($user)) {
        return View::make('profile', compact('user'));
    }
});
```

... but if you go to `mysite.com/blog` or `mysite.com/contact` or whatever, this URL would be captured by previous pattern.
Actually no problem, just register blog/contact/whatever route before, like this!

```
Route::get('blog', function(){
    return 'blog page';
});

Route::get('contact', function(){
    return 'contact page';
});

// To have username in URL discard Route::model call and add this
Route::get('{username}', function($username){
    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->fist();
    if (! is_null($user)) {
        return View::make('profile', compact('user'));
    }
});
```

Comment: So there is no way to only have the username in the URL? Sure it may just be for looks but if other sites can do it, why can't we?

Comment: Sure, there is, but not with route - model binding. I will edit answer  one more time

Answer (score 0):

You could try this without the Route::model thingy

```
Route::get('user/{username}', function($username)
{

    $user = User::where('username',$username)->first();
})
->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you can use `Route::bind()`:

```
Route::bind('user', function($value, $route)
{
    return User::whereUsername($value)->first();
});
```

Now, you can access that user without manually calling it in the route definition:

```
Route::get('{user}', function(User $user){
    if (!is_null($user)) {
        return View::make('profile', compact('user'));
    }
});
```

This will be available to all routes you define that use the `{user}` parameter.